# tsconfig.json typeroots custom path not picked up

Tags: typescript, module, tsconfig

I have some custom .d.ts files and I want tsc to pick up these files when compiling.  In order to get this done I modify the tsconfig.file to include the following

```
"typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "./app/modules"
    ]
```

./app/modules is where my custom .d.ts file resides.  Inside the ./app/modules folder I have the following file myModule.d.ts

```
export declare module myModule {
  function Login();
  function Logout();
}
```

Now inside my other typescript file I have the following import

```
import { myModule } from 'myModule';
```

Here I get the following error **Cannot find module 'myModule'.**

Comment: I am having this exact same problem, and I have posted it. To me, typeRoots does not work. For a temp workaround I added a  postinstall script which copies the types from my nested directory to the @types directory at the root.

Answer (score 10):

I found the config that fixes this. Note the `paths` and `baseUrl` properties:

```json
{
  "version": "2.1.5",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["src/subfolder/node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/subfolder/node_modules/@types/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/subfolder/node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: this seems to work for global types (as introduced by the declare module syntax), but not for declaration files which contain modules ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming to this issue with the goal of adding a folder containing custom type declarations to your project, try using the `"includes"` tsconfig option instead of the `"typeRoots"` option.

For the life of me I couldn't get the `typeRoots` property to behave as expected, but I found that you can use the `includes` property instead.

Create a folder to hold your type declarations and instead of adding that folder path to the `typeRoots` tsconfig option add it to the `includes` tsconfig option. In my usage, everything then behaves as expected.

```json
{
  "include": ["./src", "./typings"],
}
```