# Add custom typings files to Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a SPA with Angular CLI framework and a Javascript library written by a team member. I need to inject this JS file into the app.
My thought is

1. to write a type definition for the file;
2. import both JS file and its type definitions (.d.ts) to the app

My question is how to add the custom type definition file into my Angular CLI app? (I know the JS file can be added from `"scripts": []` in .angular-cli.json file, right?)

I saw some posts for adding external js library to angular-cli, but they all seem on npm which doesn't work for me apparently.

Comment: might help. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Answer (score 7):

You have a couple of options here:

1. In the `src` dir for newly created applications there is a file `typings.d.ts` which you can use reference your team member's `.d.ts` file which will expose those types throughout your application.
2. In the `tsconfig.json` file you can add the path to the `node_modules` folder where this package lives to the `typeRoots` array which will make those typing available too.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: can see a similar example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41969123