# How do I add a typings.d.ts file to an Angular 7 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am following this [tutorial here](https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements/), and the author says to add two declarations to the project's `typings.d.ts` file. However, when using the `ng-cli` to create the Angular 7 project, there is no such file generated.

In [this other article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3169-adding-custom-typings-files-d-ts-in-an-angular-2-typescript-application.htm) (for Angular 2), the author suggests to create a `typings` folder and place the `typings.d.ts` there and to modify the `tsconfig.json` file with a `files` key; doing this gives me a `TS5023: Uknown compiler option 'files'.` message.

Yet, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836379/add-custom-typings-files-to-angular-cli), the top answer suggest that `typings.d.ts` should have been created with `ng-cli` under the `src` folder, but I don't see it (I am using Angular CLI v7.3.1).

My question is, for Angular 7, how and where do I add `typings.d.ts`? What other files do I need to modify when adding such file?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to add a a `typings.d.ts`? I ask because there might be a better way

Comment: I'm trying to integrate stripe into the website. There is one Angular 7 component I found on npm, but the author has some strong disclaimers. Stripe itself doesn't have an Angular 7 module/component and only shows examples using plain JavaScript. If there's a better way, I am opened.

Comment: I guess Angular 2 article from 2016 is simply outdated for Angular 7

Comment: Have you tried `npm i -D @types/stripe`?

Comment: @Pytth I did not try that but I just went ahead and created a `typings.d.ts` under the `src` and everything works (so far). Still, though, would be nice for some official point of view and/or documentation around these types of integration problems/patterns.

Comment: I would recommend using the method I described since that seems to be the prescribed way of incorporating library types into typescript projects

Answer (score 15):

Just as you yourself said, create the typings.d.ts file in src folder and put your declarations there. That is what I do for stripe and also jquery and works fine.

```
declare var $: any;
declare var stripe: any;
declare var elements: any;
```

My latest project is on Angular 8 and worked with the same method.

Answer (score 0):

**Read the bottom first!**

I've also been following this tutorial because I want to have paymentIntent running in the front but not based on their model. Although you still need the typings.d.ts file under src with the declarations. The answer that helped me was:

> Have you tried npm i -D @types/stripe? – Pytth Feb 20 '19 at 21:20

Thanks Pytth and good luck to those that follow.

DONT go down the tutorial path, use this if you can (works with angular 4-9+):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe

Comment: So basically you are just suggesting to use the NPM to download the library instead of doing it manually? How exactly does that fix the problem of using pure JS libraries within angular?

Comment: Do or do not, at the time of the comment, I had minimal experience.. But, I had managed to get what I wanted from that library. The author never requested a pure JS lib solution, but please, feel free to downvote.